# What is the equivalent of tomcat's %F in nginx?

Tags: tomcat, nginx

Based on this [reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html):

`%F - Time taken to commit the response, in millis`

Is there an equivalent value in NGINX?

Answer (score 1):

[$upstream_header_time](https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-nginx-logging-for-application-performance-monitoring/) - Time between establishing a connection to an upstream server and receiving the first byte of the response header